# Problema SSH no Windows Server 2003

Tags: ssh, sftp

Tenho um servidor de arquivos e ele precisa ser acessado de fora da minha rede via SFTP utilizando SSH. O servidor roda Windows Server 2003 R2 e eu instalei o openSSH como servidor de SSH, e já setei todas as configurações de usuário e afins. Até ai tudo bem, pois consigo conectar no servidor, enviar arquivos, baixar arquivos, mas somente pela rede local, e quando vou tentar acessar de fora (já fiz o roteamento de portas e liberação no firewall do windows da porta 22).

---

Log do Filezilla. O 'meudominio' na verdade é o meu domínio, já tenho configurado o DNS no DomínioBR.

Estado: Conectando sftp.*meudominio*.com.br...

Resposta:   fzSftp started

Comando:    open "pmbr@sftp.*meudominio*.com.br" 22

Erro:   A conexão excedeu limite de tempo

Erro:   Não foi possível conectar ao servidor

Estado: Aguardando para tentar novamente...